# Android How to listen for Volume Button events?

Tags: java, android

I know you guys are probably tired of these kinds of posts, but why doesn't anything happen when I press volume down? I'm just trying to make a simple code, but apparently it's not working.

```
package com.cakemansapps.lightwriter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.util.Log;

public class LightWriter extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
private static final String TAG = "Touch" ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  FrameLayout main = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) 
{
    Log.w("LightWriter", "I WORK BRO.");
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

}
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493531/trying-to-catch-the-volume-onkeylongpress-not-working

Comment: Don't you need to associate your key event with controls? Did you check this link http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html

Comment: [Here you go.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2875006/420015)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I don't know if you can get long press events for the hardware keys.

I've used this code to listen for the volume button before.

```java
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
        // Do something
    }
    return true;
}
```

If that doesn't work for you let us know what device you are testing on.

**Kotlin**

```kotlin
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) { 
        // Do something
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Should the "returns true" line be inside of the 'if' block and by default it should return false? You should only return true if you handled the event.

Comment: The last line should be "return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);" instead of "return true".

Comment: This code is correct, but it will disable the main purpose which is to lessen the volume. it will prioritize the statement in the `//Do something part`

Comment: @ajdeguzman if you return false, instead of true, I think it will also change the volume accordingly.

Comment: Awesome. How do I know which volume is it lowering?... For example, if it's the System or Music or Alarm?

Comment: Thanks you saved my time...+1 for that

Comment: @AnAurelian return true will make volume button "disabled". So you can run the code without changing the volume.

Answer (score 17):

**Another approach**

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //TODO
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //TODO
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please tell how it work when device is locked

Comment: nice... how to silence/disable/hide notification when pressing volume button? =(

Comment: How to handle if screen is locked?
@Abhisheck Did you found answer for lock screen?

Comment: Is there any broadcast available to listen pressed key?

Answer (score 9):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {
        // ... your code
        return true;
    } else if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)) {
        // ... your code
        return true;
    } else
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

try these. just tested them:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        Log.w("LightWriter", "I WORK BRO.");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        Log.w("LightWriter", "I WORK BRO.");
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Sergery can you tell me how it work when device is locked

Comment: @Abhishek I've never done this... but my understanding/guess is: Your app would need permission to run when screen is locked( http://stackoverflow.com/a/11546168/2801237) and/or would likely need to setup a broadcast receiver to receive the key event (possibly one of these(and it 'might' change which device is used) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html )  (Sorry for ambiguity(I usually work on ContentProviders, Services, IPC, etc.), but hope this helps lead down right path)

Comment: onKeyLongPress() didn't work by me. However onKeyDown() works. Seems to be device dependent.

Comment: Ok, I know what the problem was. I had to call event.startTracking() in onKeyDown(). After that the onKeyLongPress() was called.

Answer (score 4):

use this code to handle Volume key event

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Up working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Down working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Although this might be working, the approach is I believe wrong. If you check the docs, `onKeyDown` is called when ANY button is pressed, `onKeyUp` is called when ANY button press is released. You can handle both `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP` and `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN` in one of them.