# Android, activity already over lock screen, but won't get any onCLick event

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, lockscreen

I want to make something like alarm activity, but it only triggered over certain push notification.
I've been pulling my hair to achieve that, combining answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545865/keep-activity-running-over-screen-lock-when-the-screens-alseep)(and many more that i couldn't refer here). Now I already can show the activity over the lock screen, but i'm stuck on getting the onClick event listener to dismiss the alarm.

So far here's my codes:

it's onCreate of my Activity:

```
 Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    setContentView(R.layout.alarm);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "Alarm");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    dismissButton.setOnClickListener(v -> Log.w("button", "Clicked"));
```

the Activity on manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".{package}.Alarm"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.WhiteAccent"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"/>
```

and it's where i call my Activity from my notificationService

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MewsAlarm.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("judul", data.get("title"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

am I did it wrong?

I only test it on my phone though (4.4.2), so i don't even know the activity will shown on other device. But really, can someone help me to get over this please?

Comment: Does this show up in the log when you click the button?
Log.w("button", "Clicked")

Comment: I believe it is in your windowmanager flags. If I recall, the WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT will not allow you to receive those onTouch events. If might be worth trying WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE instead.
Per the documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html you should use WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY

Edit: Reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/9101977/2104990

Comment: @Xenolion Yes, a service may start an Activity at any time.

Comment: Ooooh I did not know @GabeSechan

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs nope, it's not showing anything

Comment: @T-he-game yeah i know i should use WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY instead, but my phone is kitkat, as far as i know that flag is newer flag only for android O if im not mistaken. but for the TYPE_PHONE ill try it first

Comment: @T-he-game nope, the onClick still not detected, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the suggestion guys, my bad i haven't search the related topic thoroughly, so i found the answer over here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4482868/7852331

so i just add

```
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
```

to my flags above, and voila i get the click event.