# Using Nexus (Android) tablet volume buttons as click function in web

Tags: javascript

i have no code to show as i have no clue how to achieve what i need. I'm making a website (will be shown on a nexus tablet) and i would like to use the tablet's volume buttons as click function within js. is this possible? and if so, how?

thank you

Comment: I don't think its possible. Use phonegap.

Comment: Start here : [android-how-to-listen-for-volume-button-events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162705/android-how-to-listen-for-volume-button-events), that is on Java, but will give you ideas... the problem I see is accesing events that occurs on the OS and not directly in the navigator... but there may be a way...