# Launching activity on long press of volume button

Tags: android

I want to launch app when we press the volume button long time up or down button.When activity is not visible and app is present in background i.e in recent apps.Is there any solution for that. I am new to android so please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Please refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162705/android-how-to-listen-for-volume-button-events

Answer (score 0):

Just look for broadcast receiver on android developer site. You will get goo explanation with example.