# Listen to volume key button press only once

Tags: java, android

I use this code to listen to volume key button press:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27855766/2977288

But when the user holds the volume button, the listener gets fired again and again.

How can I stop that and only listen once, when the button is clicked and not when the button is press constantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` for `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP`, that way it will only fire when you release the button.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the method that handles long press, something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) 
    {
        // do what you want to do here
        return true;
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) 
    {
        // do what you want to do here
        return true;
    }

    // default action if not handled
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Sadly does not change anything