# Can I get event of volume up or down while phone ringing in android?

Tags: android

How can we get the volume up down click while there is incoming call on android phone and also mute and speaker button clicks when call is in progress. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you must first implement a way to know that there is a call, you can do this listening to the call broadcast [How to detect incoming calls, in an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device/15564021#15564021) and then react to that listening to the key events as described in [Android How to listen for Volume Button events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162705/android-how-to-listen-for-volume-button-events?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)