# How to start a Flutter service on the background whithout the need to open the app?

Tags: flutter, service, background

I've been working on a security-related app. This app sends the **location data to the server** periodically on the **background**. But I need to open the app (and click on a button) to start the service.

**Is there a way to start this service without the need to open the app in the foreground?** (Like shaking the device or clicking several times on the volume buttons)

I'm thinking maybe to start a listener on the background (through the UI) that executes the service when activated via the volume buttons?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: do u find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the updated stranded you can't keep running a service in background. To solve your purpose you can use foreground service instead. Here is the package for implementing foreground service.

https://pub.dev/packages/foreground_service

In that service you can write code for detecting Shake or Volume Button press. You can get help from the links below..

Detect shake event
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5271532/6413387

Detect Volume Button event
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162794/6413387

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will keep waiting a little longer in case someone has an implementation that can be used on iOS too.