# How to detect hardware button press in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am building an app that starts by pressing the hardware button (Android/ios volume up button) for a long time, but I can't find any way to do it,
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

**For iOS/Android:**

check out this package:

- [Volume Watcher Package](https://pub.dev/packages/volume_watcher)

---

**For Desktop/Web:**

You can use `Focus` widget or `RawKeyboardListener` widget to listen to keyboard events.

Here's a simple example:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Focus(
    autofocus: true,
    onKeyEvent: (node, event) {
      if (event.physicalKey == PhysicalKeyboardKey.keyA) {
        if (event is KeyDownEvent) {
          // the user started pressing the key A
        } else if (event is KeyRepeatEvent) {
          // the user is pressing the key A
        } else if (event is KeyUpEvent) {
          // the user stopped pressing the key A
        }
        // if you handled the event (prevent propagating the events further)
        return KeyEventResult.handled;
      }
      // otherwise return this (propagates the events further to be handled elsewhere)
      return KeyEventResult.ignored;
    },
    child: Container(),
  );
}
```

I'm using a macbook with touchbar so I couldn't confirm the volume up but you can replace `PhysicalKeyboardKey.keyA` with `PhysicalKeyboardKey.audioVolumeUp`.

Also, instead of using `autofocus`, you can use a `FocusNode` and pass it to the `Focus` widget to control when the widget has focus (i.e. when it should listen to events).

References:

- a list of all physical keys (just go to the definition of `PhysicalKeyboardKey` on the IDE to see the list):
  [keyboard_key.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/77d935af4d/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/keyboard_key.dart#L3509)
- The rendered documentation page with a DartPad example:
  [PhysicalKeyboardKey class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/PhysicalKeyboardKey-class.html)

Comment: @AnuragYadav my old answer was for Desktop/Web only -- for iOS/Android, check the updated answer -- there's a package called [Volume Watcher](https://pub.dev/packages/volume_watcher)

Comment: thanks for your help but, I want it to detect button press in the background even when the device is locked. is there any such way in flutter or nay such library? or do I need to write platform-specific code?

Comment: Here is a brief of what I want. Suppose I am making an app that turns on the flashlight on when starts, so at any point when volume button is pressed for 5 seconds it starts the app

Comment: @AnuragYadav I'm not very familiar with this area to be honest but this answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62641923/10976714

Answer (score 0):

Consider working with RawkeyEventListener widget

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).