# Cannot detect Long Press

Tags: java, android

I am using the volume up/down buttons to navigate in an activity. This works fine but i cannot use the volume down button to start the next activity. 
Also the volume is simultaneously increased/reduced. 
Here is the code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 switch(keyCode){
     case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
         event.startTracking();
         //navigation


     return true;
     case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
         //navigation

     return true;
   }


   return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.fittle.FISH"));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950215/onkeydown-and-onkeylongpress

Comment: @DanielBo i dont think so that the code is called. Otherwise it should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this little modified method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)
{
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.fittle.FISH"));
    return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) in the wrong way, try change:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.fittle.FISH"));
```

To

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, FISH.class));
```

Context can be `this` if you are calling it from activity.

Comment: @GopalRao As I understand from [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), it is generally used to send commands to different applications. And it requires you to add a proper filters in manifast

Comment: This is not the problem. I have changed the Intent but still it doesnot works.