# Distinguish between short tap (click) and long press in OnTouchListener

Tags: android, kotlin, ontouchlistener

I already found this answer: [Distinguish between long press and short press on a hardware button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137617/distinguish-between-long-press-and-short-press-on-a-hardware-button)
But I'm interested in OnTouchListener. The reason is that I want that a short press and release (click) will trigger a certain behavior, but long press (without release) will trigger a motion event to enable the user to drag the widget with their finger.

So I'm using ACTION_MOVE:

```
val listener = View.OnTouchListener(function = { view, motionEvent ->
    // check if the user gesture upon the view is of moving action
    when (motionEvent.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN-> {
            // pressed
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            view.y = motionEvent.rawY - ((view.height / 2) + 60)
            view.x = motionEvent.rawX - view.width / 2
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            // Released
```

The problem is that ACTION_MOVE will trigger immediately. Is there an option to invoke it only when the press is long? I thought maybe to use timestamps somehow to enable and disable it but is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android way to handle this is using a gesture detector. The guide topic [Detect common gestures](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector) discusses how to do this and provides sample code.

The only reason you would want to operate at the relatively low level of a touch listener is if the logic you want to implement isn't already packaged up by one of the library gesture detectors. Fortunately for you, long press and dragging are already supported gestures.

If you want to write your own logic anyway, the source code for the appropriate gesture detectors can provide you a good starting point. However, I strongly discourage that because the logic can be very tricky, with lots of edge cases to get right.

EDIT: Okay, after reading the documentation, I confess that it isn't quite as simple as I thought. But it shouldn't be very complicated, either. The problem is clear from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat.html#setislongpressenabled) for `setIsLongpressEnabled` (emphasis added):

> Set whether longpress is enabled, if this is enabled when a user presses and holds down you get a longpress event **and nothing further**.

So after a long press is detected, you won't get any scrolling call-backs. You can work around this as follows. The usual way a gesture detector is used is to write your `onTouchEvent` method as follows:

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    return if (mDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        true
    } else {
        super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

You can change this to something like the following:

```
var isLongPress = false

override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (mDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        val action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event)
        if (isLongPress && action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            // process the drag
        }    
        return true
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event)
}
```

Then in the `onLongPress` call-back, capture the event coordinates and set `isLongPress`. You can clear `isLongPress` in the `onDown` call-back. You should then ignore any call-backs to `onScroll` because, by definition, they will be happening without a long press.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm looking into it and it seems like a very simple solution

Comment: Hello Ted, I would just like to write here that while the GestureDetector is helpful for simple assignments, it's fairly limited and not flexible. For example, you cannot detect scrolling/dragging event after long-press event, the long press will block any other events, and this behaviour cannot be changed unfortunately. It seems that the only way it to directly edit the GestureDetector.java, or not use it

Comment: @sir-haver - Do you mean that after the gesture detector calls the listener's `onLongPress` method, it won't call `onScroll`? That's a bit surprising. Let me know if that's the case and I might have a suggestion or two.

Comment: Hey Ted, I mean the opposite: that after the gesture detector calls the listener's onLongPress method, it WILL call onScroll (if the user moves their finger while still long pressing). Currently, the onLongPress method blocks the onScroll method - if I'm not mistaken I could see this blocking inside GestureDetector.java, so when onLongPress is called, onScroll cannot be called. Is it possible to change this default behavior?

Comment: @sir-haver - Isn't that what you want--to drag after a long press? You can use the `onLongPress` call-back to set a flag and then ignore the scrolling unless the flag is set. (You can clear the flag in the `onDown` call-back that starts any gesture.)

Comment: Yes Ted that's what I want, but please see that after the onLongPress the onScroll cannot be called anymore, the onLongPress blocks it

Comment: @sir-haver - I'm confused. In your previous comment you said that the gesture detector "WILL call onScroll" and now you're saying that it can't be called. Which is it?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I misunderstood you, I thought we were talking about the desired outcome, yes you're totally right, after the onLongPress is called, onScroll won't be called, this the current behavior. It seems that it's done delibarately, please see line 634 in GestureDetector.java, it seems they block movement detection when onLongPress is active. Thanks and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Oh I think I got it this is very smart, so you won't process the scrolling inside onScroll because it's unreachable and instead just process it inside the onTouchEvent. Thanks a lot for all your help! Btw I don't understand why the gesture detector was designed to block onScroll after a long press, would you say, as a general question, that it's ok to just edit the GestureDetector.java, or it's something that always should be avoided? Thanks

Comment: @sir-haver - I don't know why it was designed that way either. (Obviously I had forgotten that detail about gesture detectors--it's been a while.) As to editing the code, you can't really do that. You can make a copy of the code and edit it to fit your needs. I see nothing wrong with that if that gets the job done for you. But often there's an easier way, as in my suggested approach (assuming that it works).

Comment: Ok I see, yes I will your suggestion, even though I made a "low level solution" that's working already, your solution is very elegant and simple thank you very much again