# How to start new Activity using hard Menu button?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-button, android-menu

Here is an example of the code, which just doesn't work.
I added this method in MainActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PrefActivity.class);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error trace?

Comment: giving a shot it's the first argument of the Intent constructor, 'this' 

try getting a context from your activity (

Context cont = this; 

and creating the intent like 

new Intent(cont, PrefActivity.class)

Comment: Did you define PrefActivity in the Manifest?

Comment: The error reason was beyond this method. I handled this.
This method simply doesn't work.

Comment: @cricket_007, could you please, upvote my question. I edited it. The question is absolutely different from crashing.

Comment: Why would I upvote? You still have not been specific as to **what** "doesn't work". What do you *expect* to happen?

Comment: @cricket_007. The question is "How to start new Activity using hard Menu button?" And a code, which I posted doesn't work. I can't call Preference Activity using hard Menu button.

Comment: I understand what the question is. Have you tried holding the button down? Because you implemented `onKeyLongPress`, not `onKeyDown`

Comment: @cricket_007. Yep, I've tried. Doesn't work.

Comment: @cricket_007. onKeyUp HELPED! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to click the button without holding it down, you can use `onKeyUp`.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
            return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

If you would like to handle `onKeyLongPress`, then you can read more at [onKeyDown and onKeyLongPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950215/onkeydown-and-onkeylongpress)

The reason it doesn't work is your event is being consumed by `onKeyDown`, which is continuously fired until you let go of the key and `onKeyLongPress` is never called.

Answer (score -3):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrefActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Try it!

Comment: replace this to getApplicationContext() . try it

Comment: That shouldn't change anything if `this` is a Context like an Activity anyways