# Android onkey long press not detected

Tags: android, keylistener

I am using a `ListView` in which when I long-press the down or up button the list should scroll continuously until the button is released. I have tried with `onKeyLongPress` but it's not detecting the long press of my key. Can any one help me out?

Comment: are you using a listenerer added on `fragment` or `activity` for listen the event? Can you show us some code?

Comment: This may answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7985901/945456. It looks you may need to detect the same key event in the `onKeyPress` handler and start tracking it there first.

Comment: I am designing a set top box where remote keys are used to control over it.

Answer (score 0):

```
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
        //code 
        return false;
    }
});
```

But you should put your code so we can help you to identify the problem